# SQL Server - SELECT records based on the records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table called **dbo.Tag** that looks like this:

```
Counter|TagValue
1      |CREATED
2      |REMOVED
```

And I want to only get the records that matches with my **dbo.Tag** from my other table called **dbo.Transactions**

```
Counter|TagValue
1      |CREATED
1      |UPLOADED
2      |CREATED
2      |REMOVED
3      |DELETED
4      |CREATED
4      |REMOVED
```

So, my **expected output** is this:

```
Counter|TagValue
2      |CREATED
2      |REMOVED
4      |CREATED
4      |REMOVED
```

What I **tried doing** was this query:

```
SELECT COUNTER FROM dbo.Transactions IN (SELECT * from dbo.Tag)
```

But it returned this, which is **not what I need**:
The first record, "Counter 1", should not be there because it does not have the "REMOVED" TagValue

```
Counter|TagValue
1      |CREATED
2      |CREATED
2      |REMOVED
4      |CREATED
4      |REMOVED
```

What is the proper query for doing the above?

Comment: May I ask why there is a downvote?

Comment: inner join using tagvalue and counter<>1 should do the trick

Comment: Your downvote might be due to the fact that the query you "tried" will produce an error and not the resultset you show. To use IN with a query, that query must produce a single column resultset - and "select * from dbo.Tag does not do this. Nor does it help that your 2 tables have an identical structure (as posted) and it is difficult to understand your logic. You're not new - you should have learned by now that a script containing DDL and sample data is the best way to address most sql coding problems.

Answer (score 2):

use join with filter

```
SELECT a.COUNTER,a.tagvalue FROM dbo.Transactions a
join dbo.Tag b on a.tagvalue=b.tagvalue
where a.tagvalue in ('CREATED','REMOVED') 
group by a.COUNTER,a.tagvalue
having count(distinct Tagvalue)=2)
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: @thecodeexplorer, I've edited the answer you can check n ow

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an INNER JOIN. Try out the following query.

```
SELECT A.COUNTER, A.TagValue 
FROM dbo.Transactions A
INNER JOIN  dbo.Tag B
ON A.COUNTER = B.COUNTER
AND A.TagValue= B.TagValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful for you :

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions 
WHERE Counter IN (
  SELECT Counter AS CountOf
  FROM Transactions AS T
  WHERE T.TagValue IN (SELECT TagValue FROM dbo.Tag)
  GROUP BY Counter
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=acc337e717ca718b6b4e9597e6379964)

Answer (score 0):

The following query can help in your case:

```
SELECT TA.*
FROM dbo.Transactions TA
JOIN (  SELECT [Counter]
        FROM dbo.Transactions 
        WHERE TagValue IN (SELECT TagValue FROM dbo.Tag)  
        GROUP BY [Counter]
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TagValue) = 2
) AS SQ ON SQ.[Counter] = TA.[Counter]
```

[**DEMO on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9576ecf27e3a10dffa22828305e3d0e6)